# printer not showing up on network

Tags: windows, networking, printer

Simple setup, should not be a problem, yet Im stumped.

Small office, Xerox 5050 wired directly to a linksys router. Windows 7 machines connecting wirelessly to that router. Add printer in win 7 dosent find printer. Ping the printer IP (gottev via print test page feature on printer) and get a 'destination host unreachable'. Its so simple a setup, but I have had no luck all day. This is just a small part of a larger office that uses clearOS, so possibly settings in there, but I cant find anything.

Comment: Does the printer have an ip address in the same subnet as the Windows 7 client?

Comment: Please add the networking configuration (Ips, Subnet Mask, and Gateway) of the computers and the printer device.

Comment: printer IP = 192.168.20.50   broadcast address = 192.168.20.255    subnet mask : 255.255.255.0

Comment: computer ip = 192.168.1.146 router ip = 192.168.1.1 router subnet mask = 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 5):

Judging by your comments, your printer isn`t on the same subnet as the rest of your network.

Use the following information

- Printer IP: 192.168.1.50 (or another IP address from your subnet that isn`t already taken)

  Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

  Broadcast Address: 192.168.1.255

  Gateway: 192.168.1.1

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Just for the noobs of us: "another IP" means an IP where the last number is allowed to change. The first three numbers must be the same. So 192.168.1.* and as * any (free) number from 2 to 254